# Difference between * and ?* glob in Bash

Tags: bash, wildcards

- `*` is roughly a wild card character with a unlimited amount of length.
- `?` is roughly a wild card character for one or zero length.

Is there a difference between using `*` vs `?*` when searching for strings in `bash`?

Comment: In the context of globbing or regex?

Comment: I *think* this is a globbing question, not a regular-expression question, in which case the tags should change; if it's about Bash regular expressions instead/as well then the text should change to say what it's really asking. It looks like the [tag:regular-expressions] tag was added in someone's edit so I presume that's the wrong part.

Comment: I've edited accordingly, but please revert & [edit] to say what you wanted if I got that wrong. There's confusion because "one or zero" is a regex thing, but `?*` isn't a useful thing to write in a regular expression.

Comment: Can you show an example of this "search for strings in bash"? It could be a incidentally bash while running `grep` with a regular expression, or `find` with a filename pattern, or as a wildcard.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The difference is that in `bash` (as you tagged the question) `*` matches any string with length zero or more characters, while `?*` matches a string with at least 1 character. Consider for example two files: `file.txt` and `xfile.txt` and try to list them with `ls ?*file.txt` or `ls *file.txt`.

One real case scenario when I use such construct is to list hidden files. Very often I just do

```
ls .??*
```

Double question marks are here to prevent listing the current directory `.` and the parent directory `..`, like it would be with a simpler form `ls .*`.

---

<sup>I need to point here that my `.??*` is not perfect; for example filenames with only two characters, like `.f`, don't match this pattern. More reliable solution is `ls {..?,.[!.]}*`, but usually that is too much to type for me.</sup>

Comment: find /home/?*/.[!.]?* -maxdepth 0 -perm /g+wx,o+rwx -exec chmod g-wx,o-rwx '{}' +

Comment: That is the command the lead me to this question, same strategy taken to avoid the current and parent directories.

Comment: Just an FYI, if you are using GNU coreutils (and you probably are), you can just pass `-a` to `ls` to see all files, or `-A` to see all files except `.` and `..`.

Comment: @JonathanCallen Yes of course, but for other commands that's not always the case, like for example checking the size of dot-files `du -scm .??*` vs `du -scm .*`.

Comment: `.??*` will also miss files like `.x`. Best would be to use a shell like pdksh, mksh, zsh or fish which never include `.` nor `..` in their glob expansions. Or in ksh93, set `FIGNORE` to `@(.|..)` (though that has the side effect of no longer hiding dot-files). In other shells, you'll need `.[!.]* .??*` (or `.[^.]* .??*` in some shells, which excepts in csh/tcsh will likely give you an error (by `ls`) if either of the globs doesn't match (likely the first).

Comment: I don't understand why `ll -d ./.?` matches `./..`. I thought that `?` matches ONE character (`a-z,0-9`). Any idea?

Comment: @SamuelPhan `?` matches *any* single character, including `.`.

Comment: Thanks, @jimmij. It's because the description here https://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm is confusing with the given example as it says `every other letter/number between a-z, 0-9` but it applies only for the example (where devices contain only letters & numbers). Also the first `.` character in file listing is treated differently which was confusing for me. `ll -d ./.?` matches `./..` but `ll -d ./??` doesn't.

Comment: @SamuelPhan Pathname expansion is performed by the shell. Most of them doesn't match hidden files (those started with a dot) with glob operators like `?` or `*`. That is also true for `bash` which this question/answer is about. However you can turn on dotglob option via `shopt -s dotglob` and match globs in dotfiles too. The document you are referring to is not about any specific shell, it gives just an overview of cli without going into details. If you want to learn more about bash then check out the chapter "Pathname Expansion" in the `man bash`.

Answer (score 7):

Where did you get that definition from, of to what kind of expression do you refer?

If we talk about shell expressions, both characters can be used alone, but the definition for `?` doesn't match, as then it always matches one character and not one or zero.

If we talk about regular expressions, both are operators that are placed after an expression. So in "?*" would have to be placed after something else.